# How To Evaluate This Limit and Find c?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

For a certain value of $c$, 
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty}\left[\left(x^{5} + 7x^{4} + 2\right)^c - x\right]
$$
is finite and non zero. Let $l$ be this limit. 
Calculate $l-2c$.

The answer is $1$ but I am not getting it.

Comment: btw it is only true for $x$ goes to infinity, not to minus infinity

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Well $x^5 +7x^4 + 2$ is for large $x$ "nearly" the same as $x^5$. 
As you substract $x$ the natural choice of $c$ will be $\frac{1}{5}$.

Then use the geometric sum formula to simplify the expression and find a limit if possible.

Hint:
$$a^5-b^5=(a-b)\cdot 1 = (a-b)\cdot \frac{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}=\frac{a^5-b^5}{a^4+a^3b+a^2b^2+ab^3+b^4}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
Obviously, $\ds{\color{#00f}{\large c = {1 \over 5}}}$:

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#00f}{\large%
> \ell = \lim_{x \to \infty}\bracks{\pars{x^{5} + 7x^{4} + 2}^{1/5} - x}}
> =\lim_{x \to \infty}\braces{%
> x\bracks{\pars{1 + {7 \over x} + {2 \over x^{5}}}^{1/5} - 1}}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{x \to \infty}\pars{%
> x\braces{\bracks{1 + {1 \over 5}\pars{{7 \over x} + {2 \over x^{5}}}} - 1}}
> =\lim_{x \to \infty}\braces{%
> x\bracks{{1 \over 5}\pars{{7 \over x} + {2 \over x^{5}}}}}
> =\color{#00f}{\large{7 \over 5}}
> \end{align}

$$
\color{#00f}{\large{\ell - 2c}} = {7 \over 5} - 2\pars{1 \over 5} =
\color{#00f}{\Large 1}
$$